# Disable option values in one select dropdown depending on value selected in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two select dropdowns. The first is opening times and the second is closing times. So When the user selects a opening time the closing time cannot be earlier than this.

My Jquery instead disables all the second drop down values instead of only the times earlier as can be seen here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL0d6cqL/1/).

```
    $('#open').change(function(){
        if($('#close').val()<$('#open').val()){
            $('#close').prop('disabled', true);           
        };
    })
```

How can I get the behaviour I want?

Comment: You need to retrieve the selected value from the first drop-down and then loop through the second drop-down selectively disabling appropriate options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (here is the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL0d6cqL/4/)):

```
$('#open').change(function(){
    var that = $(this);

    $('#close option').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() < that.val()) {
            $(this).prop('disabled',true);   
        } else {
            $(this).prop('disabled',false);   
        }
    });
});
```

It works on Chrome 36, but not on Firefox (haven't tested any browsers besides those two).

Since this behavior is unreliable, you might try dynamically adding options to the second `select` element based on whatever is chosen in the first `select` element.

## EDIT

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL0d6cqL/6/) based on your original fiddle. It will let you dynamically populate the second `select` element.

```
var vals = ['00.00', '00.15', '00.30', '00.45', '01.00', '01.15', '01.15'];

for(var i = 0; i<vals.length; i++) {
    $('#open').append('<option val="'+vals[i]+'">'+vals[i]+'</option>');   
}

$('#open').change(function(){
    $('#close').html('');

    for(var i = 0; i<vals.length; i++) {
        if(vals[i] >= $(this).val()) {
            $('#close').append('<option>'+vals[i]+'</option>');
        }
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks yes I've tested on Firefox and it sometimes doesn't pick up the correct values. Is it possible to dynamically add options to a another select with JQuery dependent on the first select?

Comment: @user94628, I've edited my answer and provided you with a fiddle that will let you populate the second `select` element based on the first one.

Comment: Thanks that's great. I hardly use JQuery but with `append` I could also populate any select dropdown? Plus I should also be able to easily ammend the code so if they selected the closing `select` first then the opening `select` would show only times before the closing value?

Comment: @user94628, glad I could help. Yes, that's correct. You can populate any `select` element (you can use the same paradigm shown in my answer to show times dynamically in the first `select` element as well).

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers do not allow the disabling of individual <option>s in a <select>.
I would fill the second <select> whenever the first is changed.